# Convert IEnumerable to Sum item Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ienumerable

I need to convert an IEnumerable to something else to be able to use Sum. What can I do to achieve this?

**CsTotCommit = h.Sum(x => x.CSTotCommit)**

I receive an error stating that:
CapStackTrancheDTO does not contain a definition for 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type CapStackTrancheDTO.

```
        IEnumerable<CapStackTrancheDTO> debtRank = debt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select((g,index) =>
                        new CapStackTrancheDTO
                        {
                            Rankid = index + 1,
                            CsTrancheId = g.CsTrancheId,
                            CsId = g.CsId,
                            CsTotCommit = g.CsTotCommit,
                        });


        IEnumerable<CapStackTrancheDTO> debtSum = debtRank
                      .Select(h =>
                      new
                      {
                          CsId = h.CsId,
                          CsTotCommit = h.Sum(x => x.CSTotCommit)
                      });
```

Here are the class defintions:

```
public class CapStackTrancheDTO
{
    public int? Rankid { get; set; }
    public int? CsTrancheId { get; set; }
    public int? CsId { get; set; }
    public decimal? CsTotCommit { get; set; }

}
```

There are multiple records which I want to group by CsId and SUM.

Comment: What do you need to convert it to?

Comment: I suppose I just want to be able to sum CSTotCommit. I added my error message.

Comment: You'll want to add the class definitions to this so that we can understand the types involved.

Comment: I've added the Class defintions

Comment: So are there multiple instances of `CapStackTrancheDTO` with the same `CsId` in `debtRank`? I'm trying to work out how Sum would be useful here, since you only have a single decimal value.

Comment: Yes, it's coming from a database, so there are multiple rerecords which I want to group by CsId and SUM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, you've said that you want to group by `CsId` and then sum.

Currently, you're not applying any grouping.

Use the [`.GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) method, like this:

```
IEnumerable<CapStackTrancheDTO> debtSum = debtRank
    .GroupBy(h => h.CsId)
    .Select(h =>
        new CapStackTrancheDTO
        {
            CsId = h.Key, // the value we grouped on above is now available in `Key`
            CsTotCommit = h.Sum(x => x.CSTotCommit)
        }
   );
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me! I realize that I needed Group to access .Key.